# Put every row into table cells

Tags: php

I know this sounds a little confusing, but allow me explain further.

I am taking informations from database mySql and I want to put every value into my table.

Connection

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","name_db");

$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM name_table");
```

Then

```
    $data = "";
while($r = $result->fetch_object()) {
    if ($data != "") {$data .= ",";}
    $data .= '{"value_one":"'  . $r->value_one . '",';
    $data .= '"value_two":"'   . $r->value_two . '"}';
    }
    $result->free();
$data ='{"records":['.$data.']}';
$db->close();
echo($data);
```

Next, in my index.php I have

```
<table class="hoverable responsive-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>value_one</th>
            <th>value_two</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-init="getall()">
        <tr ng-repeat="d in names | filter:search">
            <td>{{ d.value_one }}</td>
            <td>{{ d.value_two }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('usersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.getall = function() {
            $http.get("getresult.php")
                .success(function(response) {
                    $scope.names = response.records;
                });
        }

    });
</script>
```

everything looks great and works fine

**But what I need to do... I wanna put this part ( also script if it is possible )**

```
tr ng-repeat="d in names | filter:search">
            <td>{{ d.value_one }}</td>
            <td>{{ d.value_two }}</td>
        </tr>
```

**to file where I have connection etc.**

Answer (score 0):

you made it a lot more difficult than it has to be.
If you want to print every key-value pair do this

```
echo "<table><thead><th>Key</th><th>val</th></thead><tbody>";
while($r = $result->fetch_array()) {
foreach ($r as $key=>$val)
{
    echo "<tr><td>".htmlentities($key)."</td><td>".htmlentities($val)."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</tbody></table>;
}
```

if you want to put all of the data into array do this

```
$data['result']=$result->fetch_all();
$data=json_encode($data);
```

Comment: I must "send" my data into view dir where is .html file where I have defined table and put it (php piecie) into tbody. It is like modules (functions) and (views)